# Flexslider is not working in tabs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am using Magic Post Slider plugin of wordpress to display flexslider in the woocommerce product pages. I am using tabs plugin to display information and slider inside it but flexslider isn't working in tabs until i changed the browser tab or resizing browser window then flexslider is working and showing all the images.

I have apply the fix as well but still its not working. I am adding my js code here

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('a[href="#tab-product_editor_313_tab"]').click(function() {

        setTimeout(function() {
           $(window).trigger('resize');
        }, 0);

        setTimeout(function() {
           $(window).trigger('resize');
        }, 2)
    });

    var interval = 4000;
    var autoslide = true;

    interval = $(this).data("interval");

    if(interval == 0){
        autoslide = false;
    } else {
        autoslide = true;
    }

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        selector: ".slides > li",
        animation: "slide", 
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        pauseOnHover: true,
        animationLoop: true,
        animationSpeed: 300,
        slideshowSpeed: interval,
        directionNav : true,
        slideshow: autoslide,
        controlNav: false, 
        start: function(){
            $(window).resize();
        },
    });

    $(window).resize();

});
```

[image: When clicking on tab.]
[image: After changing the browser tab.]

Comment: Post screenshot or give demo url to understand the issue clearly

Comment: Okay sure @Jayanta

Comment: I have added screenshot for reference @Jayanta

Comment: let us know if your code is live ?, also check the console if you are getting any error

Comment: @PunitGajjar no i am not getting any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct code

```
    $( window ).load(function() {

$('a[href="#tab-product_editor_313_tab"]').click(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
       $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 0);

    setTimeout(function() {
       $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 2)
});

var interval = 4000;
var autoslide = true;

interval = $(this).data("interval");

if(interval == 0){
    autoslide = false;
} else {
    autoslide = true;
}

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    selector: ".slides > li",
    animation: "slide", 
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    pauseOnHover: true,
    animationLoop: true,
    animationSpeed: 300,
    slideshowSpeed: interval,
    directionNav : true,
    slideshow: autoslide,
    controlNav: false, 
    start: function(){
        $(window).resize();
    },
});

    $(window).resize();

    });
```

Comment: here is the complete code bro. please try this
only first line is changed.

Comment: I have already changed the code given by you but still result is same.

Comment: can you send me link

Answer (score -1):

I think your images path is incorrect. please inspect element and check images path.

Comment: No i have already checked that and also its working perfectly when i am changing the browser tab.

Comment: ok got the problem you have to use 

           " $( window ).load(function() {"

not
           " $(document).ready(function($) {"

Comment: Could you please let me know where i have to add this code? @shahid